# Downloading Pictures From iPhone 6

Tags: hardware, camera, software-recommendation

I use gphoto2 to download pictures from my iPhone 5 to my Raspberry Pi. Since I upgraded to an iPhone 6 I only get an error telling me that it is "unsupported" device. Are there any alternatives? *I've updated to the latest version of gphoto2.*

Comment: You're probably better off asking about this on the Apple SE site, [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Did you unlock your iPhone and say yes to the "Trust this computer" prompt?

Comment: Arecibo, I did unlock and selected trust. Thank you. Boriqua?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my expreniece with iStuff under linux goes, all of the problems disappear with installation of `libmobiledevice`. Their homepage: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/.

`libmobiledevice` is available in Ubuntu Software Center, so i suppose it can be found in default repositiories. If not:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice
```

Comment: I really doubt that ppa contains armv6hf versions of the executables, in which case this is very bad advice indeed.  They simply will not work on the pi's architecture.

Comment: @goldilocks you are right indeed. Then there's nothing more than compiling

Comment: It gave a starting point. Thanks @thekiwi5000. If I get it to work I'll mark your answer.